# How to subtract 1 hour from SQL localtimestamp?

Tags: sql

How do I subtract 1 hour from a localtimestamp in SQL?

Actually I did it as below but I am getting an error.

```
SELECT (localtimestamp - INTERVAL '0 01:00:0.0' DAY TO SECOND(1)) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()), 100);
```

Comment: In place of getdate(), you can give your localtimestamp.

Answer (score 0):

you can substract and can achive it using this query

```
select systimestamp, systimestamp - INTERVAL '1' hour from dual
```

Comment: ok, but i want output of the query like this format 07-JAN-15 11.37.44.062719000 AM only

Comment: @mqsuresh it will give you desired output

Comment: @mqsuresh: to *format* the output you should use `to_char()`